# ansible - variable within variable

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

Ansible 1.9.2 version.

Does Ansible supports variable expansion within a variable while evaluating it.

I have a task to download 3 zip files from Artifactory.

Instead of writing 3 separate tasks within the role, I used ansible's loop in the playbook. In Ansible role's default/main.yml, I have all the required variables defined/available to the role i.e. jmeterplugins_extras_artifactory_url and other (standard / webdriver) are visible to ***perf_tests*** role.

```
---
#- Download and install JMeterPlugins
# Use get_url when Ansible is 2.0+ is available on the machine (otherwise, we can't use get_url) thus, using wget.
- name: Download JMeterPlugins-*
  command: wget {{ jmeterplugins_{{ item.plugin }}_artifactory_url }}  
    chdir="{{ common_download_dir }}"
    creates="{{ common_download_dir }}/{{ jmeterplugins_{{ item.plugin }}_file }}"
  with_items:
    - { plugin: 'extras' }
    - { plugin: 'standard' }  
    - { plugin: 'webdriver' }
```

But with the above code, I'm getting an error (as shown below):

```
15:58:57 TASK: [perf_tests | Download JMeterPlugins-*] ********************************* 
15:58:57 <jmeter01.super.fast.jenkins> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: cmuser on PORT 22 TO jmeter01.super.fast.jenkins
15:58:57 fatal: [jmeter01.super.fast.jenkins] => Failed to template wget {{ jmeterplugins_{{ item.plugin }}_artifactory_url }} chdir="{{ common_download_dir }}" creates="{{ common_download_dir }}/{{ jmeterplugins_{{ item.plugin }}_file }}": template error while templating string: expected token 'variable_end', got '{'
15:58:57 
15:58:57 FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
15:58:57 
15:58:57 PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
15:58:57            to retry, use: --limit @/home/cmuser/perf_tests.retry
15:58:57 
15:58:57 jmeter01.super.fast.jenkins : ok=23   changed=6    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Doesn't ansible supports variable expansion/evaluation if a variable contains another variable (especially when I'm using a loop).

I just dont want to expand my simple loop task into 3 different -name tasks for downloading zip files for jmeterplugins_extras, jmeterplugins_standard and jmeterplugins_webdriver separately. It seems like the error is related due to Jinja.

How can I use var's value **giga** in another variable i.e. if *var* contains **giga**, then I should get the value of variable "special_giga_variable" (*{{special_{{ var }}_variable}}*)? where var was defined in defaults/main.yml as:

var: giga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't.  But it doesn't mean that you have to expand it into 3 different tasks. What you can do is actually expand you "dictionary" to look similar to this:

```
with_items:
 - {"url": "https://xxxxx", "file": "/tmp/xxxxx" }
 - {"url": "https://yyyyy", "file": "/tmp/yyyyy" }
 - {"url": "https://zzzzz", "file": "/tmp/zzzzz" }
```

Then in your task just call different parameters: `{{ item.url }} and {{ item.file }}`

Alternative Options:

1. Write your own filter that will expand your variable according to the value `{{ jmeterplugins_url | my_custom_filter(item.plugin) }}`
2. Write a custom module, that will encapsulate all of the functionality  of fetching url into the file based on your inputs
3. Write custom `lookup_plugin` that will iterate through your list of variables and produce correct result.
4. Since you are using `command` module you can leverage `bash` to concatenate your url, file in the same command ( this would probably be the messiest solution )

Comment: I like that, I did look into those last week thought I should try the simplest approach. The only issue with this is, now I have to define the actual URL and file values in the task itself (and make it more messy) instead of a more cleaner approach. But thanks Vor, I'll try this item.xxx approach. I wonder, if there's any other way to achieve what I actually wanted.

Comment: @ArunSangal I've added few more alternate solutions. They will provide much "cleaner" playbooks but will require little more work to hide all the messy concatenation.

Comment: Sure. I'm looking at those. How's this different: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][fact_name] }}. I wonder if this will work: {{ jmeterplugins_[item.plugin]_artifactory_url }} ... i.e. instead of using {{ }} to wrap the variable (which needs to be expanded), if I can use big brackets [ ]

Answer (score 27):

It does.

You can use

```
set_fact:
  variable: '{{ vars['my_' + variablename + '_variable'] }}'
```

the only downside of this approach so far is, it won't dynamically expand variables that get the value of another variable. an example:

`roles/xxx/defaults/main.yml`:

```
var1: foo
var2: '{{ var1 }}'
```

This, unfortunately will not work when trying to use the resolved value in `var2`. Hence,

```
- debug: msg='{{ vars["var2"] }}'
```

will output `{{ var1 }}` instead of `foo`.

### Workaround:

In your vars declaration, instead of using `var2: {{ var1 }}`, use `var2: '{{ vars["var1"] }}'`. That way, it will work.

Comment: Super useful! Looks like there's a global variable called vars. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: It would be nice to see an official Ansible page that documents this.  I've yet to find one and would appreciate it if anyone finds the official documentation on this.