# Ansible: can you iterate over a variable inside another variable?

Tags: ansible

I've seen this:

[ansible - variable within variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704247/ansible-variable-within-variable)

but not sure if I can apply it.

I've got this in my Ansible vars:

```
 some_text_variable: |
     A paragraph of text containing
     a list like this:
         - A
         - B
         - C
     and more text
some_other_variable: "something else"
```

which I then output in a template like this:

```
{{ some_text_variable }}
```

but I'd like to iterate within the `some_text_variable` variable somehow so I can put the `A`, `B`, `C` elements externally.

i.e. so I could output `some_text_variable` in one play and it has `A`, `B`, `C` but in another play it might have `D`, `E`, `F`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you won't be able to iterate "a list like this"  list. it will just print as it is list in the template output.

are you using something like this.

some_text_variable:
  - var1
  - var2
  - list1
    - "A"
    - "B"
    - "C"

or A,B and C are variables?

Answer (score 1):

Let's iterate. The play below

```
vars:
  my_list:
    - A
    - B
    - C
tasks:
  - set_fact:
      some_text_variable: |
        A paragraph of text containing
        a list like this:
        {% for item in my_list %}
            - {{ item }}
        {% endfor %}
        and more text
      some_other_variable: "something else"
  - debug: msg="{{ some_text_variable.split('\n') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
"A paragraph of text containing", 
"a list like this:", 
"    - A", 
"    - B", 
"    - C", 
"and more text", 
""
]
```